# python pandas groupby: percent of key2 values of key1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I grouped it by two keys `df.groupby(['key1',key2'])`. For each key2 entry, how do I display the its percent of key1 values?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative method using one groupby statement.

Group by k1, select column k2 and apply a lambda function.  The lambda gets frequency counts for each level of k2 *within* k1 and then we divide by the count of k1:

```
In [1]: df.groupby('k1')['k2'].apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x)/x.count().astype(float))

Out[1]:
k1
a   x    0.500000
    y    0.500000
b   y    0.666667
    x    0.333333
```

Performance:

HYRY's method:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 3.07 ms per loop
```

My method:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.98 ms per loop
```

Comment: Hi @gus, if this is the answer you were looking for, it would help to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

call groupby twice for "k1" and ("k1", "k2"), and then do `div`:

```
import pandas as pd
k1 = ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]
k2 = ["x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "y", "y"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"k1":k1, "k2":k2})

df.groupby(["k1", "k2"]).k2.count().div(
    df.groupby("k1").k1.count().astype(float), level=0)
```

output:

```
k1  k2
a   x     0.500000
    y     0.500000
b   x     0.333333
    y     0.666667
```